# Did Spanish have declensions? - ¿Alguna vez se declinó en español?

Tags: gramática, historia

Como el español tiene como antecesor al latín, y en latín uno tiene que declinar los sustantivos, tiene sentido preguntarse si, en el español, o un antecesor cercano (quizá español muy antiguo) hubo alguna vez en la que se declinó.

---

Since Spanish evolved from Latin, and Latin has cases (Nominative, Acusative, Dative, Genitive, Ablative) did Spanish nouns change, sometime ago, with respect to cases?

Comment: http://www.meneame.net/story/espanol-frances-perdieron-declinaciones#c-15

Comment: http://www.elcastellano.org/ns/edicion/2008/septiembre/latin.html

Comment: Gracias por el enlace @belisarius, es muy interesante.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Las declinaciones empezaron a perderse ya con el latín vulgar y en romance, pasando de cinco a tres, sobre todo por perdida de la «m» en acusativo y el cambio de la «u» final en «o» (o ambas cosas, por ejemplo, «amicus» acabará siendo «amigo»). Como esta simplificación acabaría por producir confusiones, fueron sustituidas por preposiciones, que expresaban con más claridad las funciones gramaticales del sustantivo, quedando reducidos a tres tipos: terminados en «a», en «o» y en «e» o consonante, y que en español se pueden considerar etimológicamente procedentes del acusativo.

Hay que tener en cuenta que el cambio no fue repentino ni uniforme en todos los sectores sociales. Junto al castellano primitivo del pueblo llano, considerado entonces vulgar («rusticus sermo») convivía un latín vulgar influido por las lenguas romances, que conservaba restos de la declinación, y el latín culto mantenido por el clero, algún noble y poco más.

Por decirlo de algún modo, seguimos declinando a nuestra manera con los pronombres de modo que los hay tónicos (nominativos-vocativos) como «él», y átonos dativos («le») o acusativos («lo»), así como ablativos («conmigo»). Supongo que a los posesivos («suyo») podrían considerarse genitivos, pero no he visto referencias de esto. Por la función original del latín, también se habla de complementos directos  o acusativos, complemento indirectos  o dativos y circunstanciales o ablativos, y el genitivo sería asimilable al complemento de nombre.